# how to execute code only for old versions of my app

Tags: android, version

i want to do some things in my code only for the old version of my app(not android version my apps version code ) not for the new downloads i tried to use this

```
try {
     version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(version<2) {

}
```

and put loges in the if statement and i download my app what the current version is 1 and in my code i changed it to 2 and run it with the code above  and it never reach he if block i assuming because it update the version before onCreate.
so my question is where should i put that if statement or is there a other way how to accomplish this.
 thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check android version :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}
```

**Update:**

Use `BroadcastReceiver` to hock upgrade action.

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.OnUpgradeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.app.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: thanks but i mean my own apps version not androids sorry for not being clear in my question i edit it already. but thanks anyway.

Comment: thanks it worked! i used android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED because my app is above api 12.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
```

get the version code:

```
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Later use and `"if"` to execute what you need.